# Why do some websites have weird scrolling mechanics?

Tags: macos

I'm not sure if this issue is specific to macs, but I'm guessing it is because mac has its own special scrolling features.

Almost every website and app on a mac has a specific feel to its scrolling. You get familiar with it after a while, and your fingers adjust to it so that you feel comfortable scrolling through webpages, apps, etc.

But then once in a while, I come across a website where the scrolling feels totally different. It starts slow, and then suddenly accelerates mid-scroll and doesn't slow down at the rate I'd expect. It's hard to describe what's so jarring about it, but it's really annoying given that any mac user has probably adjusted to the typical mac scrolling mechanics.

[Here's an example](https://us.oneill.com/collections/mens-new-arrivals-1) of what I'm talking about.

Is there a way to disable this, or are we at the mercy of the website designer?

EDIT: [Better (or worse) example](https://dlinkers.com/)

EDIT (2023, four years later): Both the links above now have good scrolling. Maybe web designers have realized everyone hates [scrolljacking](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrolljacking).

Comment: The site you gave scrolls just fine in my opinion.
I think what you explain is that on the one page scrolling will go slower because the page is still loading some stuff, and once that's all done, you can scroll as fast as you can no?

Comment: It's definitely not a loading issue—I've encountered the same thing on sites where everything loads just fine. It's the jerky acceleration of the scrolling in response to the trackpad finger movement. Maybe it depends on the browser? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Here's a better example: https://dlinkers.com/

Comment: On Firefox for Dev, it's not scrolling the same!

Comment: This behavior is only on Chrome, so you should file a defect.

Comment: I found this in the code of the page:

"    }
    function o(e) {
        x || t();
        var o = e.target
          , r = l(o);
        if (!r || e.defaultPrevented || s(w, "embed") || s(o, "embed") && /\.pdf/i.test(o.src))
            return !0;
        var a = e.wheelDeltaX || 0
          , i = e.wheelDeltaY || 0;
        return a || i || (i = e.wheelDelta || 0),
        !v.touchpadSupport && f(i) ? !0 : (Math.abs(a) > 1.2 && (a *= v.stepSize / 120),
        Math.abs(i) > 1.2 && (i *= v.stepSize / 120),
        n(r, -a, -i),
        void e.preventDefault())
    }

Comment: I think the value stepSize / 120 is to high or something?
I found those lines between these comments:
"Smooth Scroll"
and
"End of Smooth Scroll"

Comment: Interesting, Firefox is behaving better for me too (though a bit of a shaky tremor thing instead). Safari is as bad or worse than Chrome, interestingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93751/discussion-between-dakta-moriame-and-willg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example scrolls fine for me, however in both Safari and Chrome https://dlinkers.com/ scrolls abnormally (too) fast.

This has nothing to do with you, your browser, or with Macs in general. The blame is the website/web developer. There is JS somewhere telling it to scroll weird. I am too lazy to find it but its definitely there. If you want to test, disable JS on your browser and while to content won't load (again, more crappy design by the web devs) it will scroll properly.

TBH there's no solution to the problem other than contacting the company. When I come about sites with crappy design, unless I really need it, I will click off and find an alternative site. You don't deserve my business if you can't get basic things correct on your site.

One other solution is manually scrolling with the scroll bar on the right. Permanent viewing of the scroll bars can be enabled in `System Preferences > General`. [image]

Comment: That's exactly that @JBis and I looked it up, and is found in the
"jquery.plugins.js" 
under:
"SmoothScroll for Websites"
at line 2120
If I'm not mistaken.